# Unable to configure a local WML provider in CP4D 2.5

Tags: watson-openscale

I have OpenScale and WML installed on CP4D 2.5. When I try to configure OpenScale to use the local WML provider I receive the following error:

Error
There was an error while saving the configuration. 
Failed to connect to ML provider. Please check your credential is correct.

You can Try Again or click Cancel to change the configuration.

Reviewing the logs in the aiopenscale-ibm-aios-ml-gateway-discovery-XXX pod, I see an exception with this message:

{"class":"com.ibm.aios.service.common.rest.HttpRest$2","method":"handleResponse","trace_id":"dgxqqj0vxljwma7gw1jjfc5my","transaction_id":"d320302b-89f2-4d05-a0a1-2f7c3f1e2608","timestamp":"2020-06-05T17:31:01.026Z","log_level":"SEVERE","message_details":"AIQGS0046E : Status Code 401 with response {'status':401,'reason':'Unauthorized','details':{'trace':'ee5d139e-c228-4d4f-8a87-5debd6d080f6','errors':[{'code':'token_format_is_unsupported','message':'Provided token should be in bearer token format','target':{'type':'header','name':'Authorization'}}]}}.","exception":"org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: {\"status\":401,\"reason\":\"Unauthorized\",\"details\":{\"trace\":\"ee5d139e-c228-4d4f-8a87-5debd6d080f6\",\"errors\":[{\"code\":\"token_format_is_unsupported\",\"message\":\"Provided token should be in bearer token format\",\"target\":{\"type\":\"header\",\"name\":\"Authorization\"}}]}}\n\tat

Anyone that might faced and solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the admin user is a member of the space that you are trying to connect to. That should solve the problem.

-Manish